# Firestore aggregation queries beta C#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

According to [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries) there presently (Nov '22) a beta version for aggregate queries. These allow you to count documents in a much more cost-effective way than traditionally.

The documentation mentions several languages but C# is not present on that list. Does anybody know whether this feature will be supported in C#? Does anybody know when the C# SDK might be released? Does anybody know when this feature might be available out of beta?

Comment: This question doesn't really belong on Stack Overflow.  Consider addressing the Firebase staff directly using the [firebase-talk](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk) group.